# Chrome: Disabling the user ability to use the navigate to the previous page in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome

As the last page in an eCommerce site I have been asked to prevent the user going back to the previous payments page so they cannot order the same product again.

Site is designed using Angular 7

The previous page creates an order from a Quote and routes to the confirmation page.

I have implemented a solution, in the code below, that seems to work in most situations - In IE, Firefox once I navigate to the confirmation page via the route you cannot use the back button or shortcut to return to the previous page

However: In Chrome, if you don't interact with the page in any way you can click the back button to navigate back. If you interact with the page, e.g. click it, add any details to a textbox etc, you are then prevented from going back.

```
preventBackButton() {
    window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.href);
    window.onpopstate = () => {
      window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.href);
    };
  }
```

Issue: When clicking back button on Chrome the window.onpopstate does not fire.